# How to get a refresh token for service account in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wasn't able to figure out how to obtain a refresh token for the service account in Google Cloud.

Here is my case:
I can get an access token for a service account with the following command:

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token' | jq .


{
"access_token": "xxx",
"expires_in": 3241,
"token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

I want to refresh the token before the expiration time.

Answer (score 2):

Access tokens issued by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server expire one hour after they are issued. When an access token expires, then the application should generate another JWT, sign it, and request another access token. This is explained at [1]

[1]https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#expiration